# Where i can place timeline.js in my app? For gtmetrix

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/common/timeline/timeline.css">
<script defer src="/src/common/timeline/timeline-min.js"></script>
```

I want to place this to code in my project for compile and compress to save place and update speed.
But i have an error [image]

[image]

How to do it correct?

Comment: you wrote it in your index.html ?

Comment: yes, can i use in webpack it? this plugin https://timeline.knightlab.com/ ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep the file on same level as index html?

```
    public/
          index.html
          timeline.js
          timeline.css
```

And in `index.html` use like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./timeline.css">
<script defer src="./timeline.js"></script>
```

If you want to keep the files somewhere else (say `src` folder) and manage using it using `webpack`, you can use `copy-webpack-plugin`

```
   const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

    plugins : [
          // Some other plugins
          new CopyPlugin([
            { from: "./common/timeline/timeline.css", to: "./timeline.css" },
            { from: "common/timeline/timeline.js", to: "./timeline.js" }
          ])]
```

And refer the files using the same code as before

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./timeline.css">
<script defer src="./timeline.js"></script>
```